# Setting the viewport width via javascript - Desktop version on iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, css, mobile, breakpoints

I am trying to have iOS Safari to dynamically set the viewport's width so that I can get a desktop view on mobile. We have the external stylesheet for mobile breakpoints separated out into Breakpoints.css.

The method here is to disable Breakpoints.css and change the viewport to 1024px.

This seems to work perfectly on Chrome's dev tools, but not on an actual iPhone.

**Note:** The goal is to change the look to desktop view, on the fly, without having to reload the page. My guess is that iOS Safari is changing the viewport and disabling the Breakpoints.css, but it's not re-rendering the page since it's already loaded.

Here is the link to toggle the desktop version:

`<a id="breakCSSButton" href="#">Toggle Desktop/Mobile View</a>`

Here is the code:

```
$(function () {
    var breakpointLinkTag = $('link[href="Breakpoints.css"]');

    $('#breakCSSButton').click(function () {
    breakpointLinkTag.prop("disabled", (_, val) => !val);
    viewportBreak = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
    viewportBreak.setAttribute('content', 'user-scalable=1, width=1024px, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=4');
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just append the html meta tag into the document using

```
.html('<meta= " ">')
```

using the content tag is generally used for the before and after classes in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this. Something about removing the breakpoints external stylesheet got in the way.

I also added a `$( window ).resize();` to ensure the viewport adjustment without having the page actually reload.